# Configurar backend y frontend en 2 micros de Deta.space

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo este código de mi aplicación nodejs express, donde sirvo archivos estáticos desde la carpeta "public" usando `express.static` y luego hago el deploy en deta usando un micro y funciona perfecto.

**DOCUMENTACIÓN DE ROUTING DE DETA:** https://deta.space/docs/en/basics/micros#micro-routing

Esta es la configuración del archivo Deta que uso actualmente y funciona bien:

```
v: 0
micros:
  - name: web
    src: .
    engine: nodejs16
    primary: true
```

Index.js:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.deta.app'
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api1', async (req, res) => {
//code
});

app.post('/api2', async (req, res) => {
//code
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
}
```

**Pero quiero usar un micro para servir los archivos estáticos de "public" usando un engine estático y el index.js con un micro separado usando de engine nodejs.**

Por más que lo intento no puedo hacerlo. Si uso esta configuración sirvo la carpeta `public` en la raiz del dominio, pero obtengo un error 404 cuando hago cualquier petición del lado del cliente a `/api1` o `/api2`.

```
v: 0
micros:
  - name: web
    src: .
    engine: nodejs16
  - name: frontend
    src: public
    engine: static
    primary: true
    public: true
    serve: .
```

En resumen quiero servir la carpeta public en la raiz del dominio usando un engine static y el archivo `index.js` con las rutas `api1` y `api2` con un motor "nodejs16".

PD: En mi carpeta local y la estructura es:
[image: deta]